# migrate to console application and user input

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, console-application

I'm using .net application with c#, but I want to migrate it to c# console application

class:

```
static class StringExtensions 
{
     public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength) 
     {
         if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
         if (partLength <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

         for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
            yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
      }

}
```

calling:

```
var parts = "32427237".SplitInParts(3);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parts));
```

//the output are 324 272 37

so I want to user input values, for example 123456789, and split output are 123 456 789, how can I do it on console app?

------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------------------

COMPLETE CODE:

```
namespace prw
{
    class Program
    {
        public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
        {
            if (s == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
            if (partLength <= 0)
               throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

            for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
               yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
        }




         private static void Main(string[] args)
         {
            var input= Console.ReadLine();
            var parts = input.SplitInParts(3);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parts));   
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: use console.readline()!

Comment: but if I want to create new console proyect, just copy my code and change writeline for read line?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input= Console.ReadLine();
        var parts = input.SplitInParts(3);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", parts));   
   }
}
 public static class Util
{
    public static IEnumerable<String> SplitInParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        if (partLength <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Part length has to be positive.", "partLength");

        for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
            yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an code error... when I declare this String s, it says extension method can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static class. I upload my code

Comment: Excelent, tank you so much! @Arash jo

Comment: @GerardoVentas , you might want to click the gray tick beside his answer if it worked for you.